# Possible to create an authorized Client from FirebaseAuth to access GoogleApis in Flutter Web?

Tags: dart, google-api, flutter-web, google-secret-manager

I am trying to use the SecretManagerApi in my Flutter Web app.

This is what I got so far:

```dart
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/secretmanager/v1.dart';
...
final client await clientViaApplicationDefaultCredentials(
    scopes: [FirestoreApi.cloudPlatformScope]);
final api = SecretManagerApi(client);
final secrets = await api.projects.secrets.versions.access(<YOUR_SECRET_NAME>);
print(secrets.payload!.data.toString());
...
```

but this fails because `clientViaApplicationDefaultCredentials` uses `dart:io` which is not available for Flutter Web.

Since I use Firebase to authenticate my users, I was wondering if it is possible to create such an authenticated client from the Firebase authentication data?

After all, the user is already authenticated for/with a Google product.

If this is not possible, how can I create an authenticated client for a Flutter Web App?

Here are some additional requirements:

- I don't want to use GoogleAuth as authentication method for Firebase
- I don't want any popups or consent screens